# How to handle two configureStore files for Redux in TypeScript (multiple module.exports)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, tsx

I'm building a React Native app with TypeScript using Redux for my state.

I like using two seperate files for `configureStore`. In JS This looks like this:

`configureStore.dev.js`:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux";
import logger from "redux-logger";

import reducers from "../reducers";

const configureStore = () => {
  const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(logger));
  return store;
};

export default configureStore;
```

`configureStore.prod.js`:

```
import { createStore } from "redux";

import reducers from "../reducers";

const configureStore = () => {
  const store = createStore(reducers);
  return store;
};

export default configureStore;
```

`configureStore.js`:

```
import Config from "react-native-config";

if (Config.REACT_ENVIRONMENT === "staging") {

  module.exports = require("./configureStore.dev");
} else {
  // tslint:disable-next-line no-var-requires
  module.exports = require("./configureStore.prod");
}
```

And then within `App.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Orientation from "react-native-orientation";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import Navigator from "./navigation/Navigator";
import configureStore from "./redux/store/configureStore";

export const store = configureStore();

export default class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    Orientation.lockToPortrait();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Navigator />;
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

The problem now with TypeScript is that - after converting these files to `.ts` and `.tsx` - this code throws linting errors (and it furthermore blocks all Jest unit tests from running).

The lines where `modules.exports` exports the respective file depending on environment variables throws the error:

```
[tslint] require statement not part of an import statement (no-var-requires)
```

And in `App.tsx` the import of `configureStore` throws:

```
[ts] Module '"/Users/jan/Documents/FullStackFounders/PainButton/painbutton/app/redux/store/configureStore"' has no default export.
```

How would one handle this case in TypeScript?

The only solution I could come up with was only using one file and using a lot of if's for all the Dev only configs. But that doesn't seem clean to me.

Comment: The code you posted contains no module.exports and no require. How are .prod and .dev conditionally imported?

Comment: @estus Whoopsie, forgot one file. I added it!

Comment: You likely need second `// tslint:disable-next-line no-var-requires` there. As for `has no default export`, I'm not sure why it's there. Make sure you have `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` and `esModuleInterop` enabled, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are mixing `import / export` and `require / module.exports` syntax.
Try to use dynamic import expressions.

**configureStore.js**

```
export default Config.REACT_ENVIRONMENT === "staging" ? import("./configureStore.dev") : import("./configureStore.prod");
```

**main render file**

```
import configure from "./configureStore.js";

configure.then(configFunc => {
    const store = configFunc();

    ReactDOM.render(<App store={store} />, document.querySelector("#root"));
})
```

Pass the `store` as a prop to the `<App />` Component.

I hope it will help.